# How it work the Spring @Autowired annotation on a constructor?

Tags: java, spring, frameworks, annotations, spring-annotations

I am studying Spring framework and I have the following doubt related the **@Autowired** annotation on the constructor of this example:

```
@Component
public class TransferServiceImpl implements TransferService {

    @Autowired
    public TransferServiceImpl(AccountRepository repo) {
        this.accountRepository = repo;
    }
}
```

So what exactly mean? That the **AccountRepository repo** object (definied as a **component** somewhere) is automatically injected into the  **TransferServiceImpl()** constructor?

How it work this operation? Is it done by type? (because **AccountRepository** is a **singleton** for Spring default), or what?

Tnx

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Spring will look for the `AccountRepository` bean in the container. There are multiple possible scenarios:

1- There are zero beans with the type `AccountRepository`. An exception will be thrown.

2- There is one bean with the type `AccountRepository`. The bean will be injected when `TransferServiceImpl` is constructed.

3- There are more than one bean with the type `AccountRepository`:

- Fallback to the bean name. In this case, Spring will look for a bean of type `AccountRepository` with name `repo`. If a match is found, it will be injected.
- The name fallback fails (multiple beans with the same type and name). An exception will be thrown.

Answer (score 5):

With `@Component` you tell the scan process that this class is a bean, with `@autowire` you tell the post processor to search through the spring repository for a bean of type `AccountRepository`. If the bean is found, it will be used with the annotated constructor. Based on the scope, a new instance will be used (`prototype`) or an already instanciated bean will be passed (`singleton`). If in anyway there are two beans matching the constructor argument, an exception will be thrown.